# Encontrar Lugares-cercanos dependiendo de mi ubicación

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

estoy generando una pagina donde me indique mi ubicación en la que me encuentro con la `API de geolocalización de Google`, ademas que me muestra las cafeterías mas cercanas a mi ubicación, e encontrado varios ejemplos y me funcionan pero no me muestra mi ubicación en la que me encuentro tiene como diferencia 1km mas o menos, saben a que se debe, necesito de su ayuda ya que he probado con todo y no me queda, se los agradezco de corazón....  Les dejo el codigo en el que me estoy basando....

```js
function success(position) {  
 var status = document.querySelector('#status');  
 status.innerHTML = "¡ESTA ES SU UBICACIÓN!";  
 
 var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');  
 mapcanvas.id = 'mapcanvas';  
 mapcanvas.style.height = '300px';  
 mapcanvas.style.width = '100%';  
 
 document.querySelector('#map').appendChild(mapcanvas);  
 
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
 var myOptions = {
 zoom: 15,
 center: latlng,
 mapTypeControl: false,
 navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };  
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), myOptions);  
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
 position: latlng,
 map: map,  
 title:"Usted está aquí."
 });  
} 
 
function error(msg) {  
 var status = document.getElementById('status');  
 status.innerHTML= "Error [" + error.code + "]: " + error.message;
}  
 
if (navigator.geolocation) {  
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error,{maximumAge:60000, timeout: 4000});  
} else {  
 error('Actualiza el navegador web para usar el API de localización');  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>...</title>
    <!-- CSS de Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web' rel='stylesheet" type='text/css'>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagenes/logo-mapa.png" />
  <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
      <div class="mapa">
        <div id="contenedor">
          <p id="status">Buscando su localización…</p>  
          <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
        <br/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Dónde estás testeándolo? ¿En un pc? Ten en cuenta que la ubicación obtenida de la triangulación de la posición mediante redes de telefonía tiene errores sustanciales y la posición que te da es "la que hay".

Comment: Si en un PC, entonces de cual forma me recomiendan que resuelva ese proyecto, lo que pasa que quiero que si yo estoy en cierto lugar me muestre cuantas cafeterías están cerca de mi, teniendo las coordenadas de cada lugar que busco yo, como puedo implementarlas?

Comment: Hola! @R.C.Ana se que es algo tarde pero me preguntaba ¿lograste hacerlo? En mi caso yo tengo un array de coordenadas y quiero comparla con la coordenada A, entonces quiero sacar de esa array el que este más cerca de la coordenada A

Comment: @Izlia, no no pude implementar esa parte, además de que esos requerimientos me los cambiaron y ya no continúe con eso que estaba trabajando..